# How to simulate a multi propagation of a laser beam in atmospheric turbulence?

Tags: python

I want to simulate how a Gaussian beam would look like at the receiver plane when propagated through an atmospheric turbulence. For this I am using [AO](https://github.com/AOtools) package. Since I didn't see any function for multipropagation i.e. choosing multiple phase screens between the distance and propagating partially. Taking reference from the book "Numerical Simulation of optical wave propagation with examples in Matlab", i modified the source code for angularSpectrum().[image: matlab code]

My code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""


@author: 
"""
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from aotools import phasescreen, opticalpropagation, atmos_conversions, fouriertransform


class beam:
    def __init__(self, sigma, Eo, z, x, lambda_, r0, N, delta, L0, l0, num):
        self.sigma = sigma
        self.Eo = Eo
        self.z = z
        self.x = x
        self.y = x
        self.X,self.Y = np.meshgrid(self.x, self.y)
        self.lambda_ = lambda_
        self.r0 = r0
        self.N = N
        self.delta = delta
        self.L0 = L0
        self.l0 =l0
        self.num = num
        
    def electric_field(self):  #generate a Gaussian beam 
        return self.Eo * np.exp(-0.5*(self.X **2 + self.Y**2)/self.sigma**2)
    
    
    def PS(self):    #generate phase screens
        phase_arr = []
        for i in range(self.num):
            phase_arr.append(phasescreen.ft_sh_phase_screen(self.r0, self.N, self.delta, self.L0, self.l0, seed = None))
        return np.array(phase_arr)
    
    def angularSpectrum(self, inputSpacing, outputSpacing, t):   #modified this from source code
        """
        Propogates light complex amplitude using an angular spectrum algorithm
    
        Parameters:
            inputComplexAmp (ndarray): Complex array of input complex amplitude
            wvl (float): Wavelength of light to propagate
            inputSpacing (float): The spacing between points on the input array in metres
            outputSpacing (float): The desired spacing between points on the output array in metres
            z (float): Distance to propagate in metres
    
        Returns:
            ndarray: propagated complex amplitude
        """
        wvl = self.lambda_
        z = self.z
        inputComplexAmp = self.electric_field()
        # If propagation distance is 0, don't bother 
        # if self.z==0:
        #     return inputComplexAmp
        mag = float(outputSpacing)/inputSpacing
        N = self.N
        k = 2*np.pi/wvl     #optical wavevector
    
        (x1,y1) = np.meshgrid(inputSpacing*np.arange(-N/2,N/2),   #receiver plane meshgrid
                                 inputSpacing*np.arange(-N/2,N/2))
        r1sq = (x1**2 + y1**2) + 1e-10
        Q1 = np.exp( 1j * k/2. * (1-mag)/delta * r1sq)  #not changed
        Uin = inputComplexAmp *Q1 * t[0]
        w = N * 0.47
        sg = np.exp(-(self.X**2 + self.Y**2)**8/(w**16))
        for idx in range(self.num):
        
        #Spatial Frequencies (of source plane)
            df1 = 1. / (N*inputSpacing)
            fX,fY = np.meshgrid(df1*np.arange(-N/2,N/2),
                                   df1*np.arange(-N/2,N/2))
            fsq = fX**2 + fY**2
        
            #Scaling Param
            
            
            Q2 = np.exp(-1j * np.pi**2 * 2 * z/mag/k*fsq)
            Uin = sg * t[idx]*fouriertransform.ift2(
                        Q2 * fouriertransform.ft2(Uin/mag,inputSpacing), df1)
            #Observation Plane Co-ords
        x2,y2 = np.meshgrid( outputSpacing*np.arange(-N/2,N/2),
                                outputSpacing*np.arange(-N/2,N/2) )
        r2sq = x2**2 + y2**2
    
        #Quadratic phase factors
    
        Q3 = np.exp(1j * k/2. * (mag-1)/(mag*z) * r2sq)
    
        #Compute propagated field
        outputComplexAmp = Q3 * Uin*Q1
        return outputComplexAmp


    def Fresnelpropagation(self):  #optical propagation
        phase_arr = self.PS()
        Uout = self.angularSpectrum(self.delta, self.delta, phase_arr)
        return np.array(Uout)
        
        
    def avg_real(self):  #take average of few iterations
        
        av_m = 100
        Uout = self.Fresnelpropagation()
        Uav = np.zeros((Uout.shape))*1j
        for i in range(av_m):
            Uav += Uout
        
        return Uav/av_m
    

    
def plot_(Uin,G):
    # Assuming you have defined m, X, Y, and G appropriately for each propagating distance

    m = G.shape[0]
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, m+1)  # Create n subplots in a single row
    ax[0, 0].imshow(np.abs(Uin), cmap = 'viridis')
    ax[1, 0].imshow(np.imag(Uin), cmap = 'viridis')  # Display the absolute values of G[i] in each su
    for i in range(1,m+1):
        ax[0, i].imshow(np.abs(G[i-1]), cmap = 'viridis')
        ax[1, i].imshow(np.imag(G[i-1]), cmap = 'viridis')  # Display the absolute values of G[i] in each subplot

    plt.show()  # Display the plot
def func(cn2_,N):   #try for a few cn2 values
    count = 1
    for cn2 in cn2_:
        
        x = np.linspace(-D/2,D/2,N)
        print(N)
        r0 = atmos_conversions.cn2_to_r0(cn2, lambda_)
        print(D/r0)
        z = 1e2   #distance between two phase screens
        #convert cn2 to ro 
        # sigma, Eo, z, x, lambda_, r0, N, delta, L0, l0, num
        g = beam(sigma, Eo, z, x, lambda_, r0, N, delta, L0, l0, num)
        Uin = g.electric_field()
        Uav.append(g.avg_real(count))
        count += 1
    print(np.array(Uav).shape[0])
    plot_(Uin, np.array(Uav))
        
# plt.imshow(gaussian.electric_field())
D = 0.3  #receiver size
N = 100  #phase screen grid size 
num = 10  #numner of phase screen
Eo = 1
delta = D/N   #size of each pixel in a phase screen grid 
L0 = 1  #the outer scale
l0 = 0.05   #the inner scale 
lambda_ = 1064*10**(-9)   #1064nm
sigma = 0.01   #for beam width
  #different values of cn2[![output][2]][2]
cn2_ = [1*10**(-19), 1*10**(-13), 1*10**(-10)]
Uav = []  
func(cn2_,N)
```

I don't know if i did it correctly but the output I see is weird. I'd appreciate some help with understanding the output, if the code is correct. P.S the first plot is the source and the rest are on the basis of increasing atmospheric turbulence.

when running code for multiple times, i get different results. I do understand that the turbulence is random but shouldn't the output be somewhat similar based on the cn2 values?
Output:

[image: fig 1]
[image: fig2]
[image: fig 3]
[image: fig 4]

Comment: Can you add some of the equations involved? This would help clarify your question

Comment: I think I got my problem solved.